# I have a tile layer in a webmap, I want to create a function that calls the tile layer and returns a value at when the tile layers scale changes

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements, gis, arcgis-js-api

So I have a function for inserting a tile layer

```
var layer = new TileLayer({
  //  url: "https://servicesbeta.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Firefly_World_Imagery/MapServer"

  });
  map.add(layer);
```

As you zoom in and out, the scale changes.

I wrote a function that says if the minscale is 500,000 then please return a value of 32 and else return a value of 7.

```
var scale_condition= {
  if (layer.minScale<=500000){
    return 32;
  },
  else{
    return 7;
  },

  };
```

Instead I get nothing. This does not seem to difficult, so I' am wondering what am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you want your `scale_condition` function to be called every time the map is zoomed-in or zoomed-out?

Comment: That is what i need the scale_condition function to do.

Comment: i've looked into view.watch and it acknowledges the change in scale. However it does not make the change to symbol marker.